# Interesting Fibonacci sequence pattern

Tags: fibonacci-numbers

For the equation
$x^2+1$ is divisible by $y$ and $y^2+1$ is divisible by $x$ the solutions come out to be alternate terms of the Fibonacci sequence that is (1,2) (2,5) (5,13) (13,34) (34,89) and so on.

I would like to know the proof or reason for this.

Comment: Maybe you can find your answer at the pages 34 and 35 of [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Fibonacci-Lucas-Numbers-Golden-Section/dp/0486462765/ref=pd_sbs_14_t_1/159-5746834-6001269?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=C712G3XJW79YX2CM6YXQ). In fact, you can write the [Cassini formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities) as equation like this $y^2-xy-x^2=1$ where $x=F_{2i}$ and $y= F_{2i+1}$. I hope to be helpful.